# Rounding calculated values of parameters in TikZ when an integer is required

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I can't get the full labeling of the x axis in the following graph (intended to serve as a template for different values of the parameters).

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{siunitx}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc}
\newcommand{\ProgTemp}[4]% #1=T_amb,#2=T_plateau, #3=rate, #4=t_plateau
{
% grid
\draw[style=help lines, ystep=100, xstep=1, ultra thin, color=pink] (0,0) grid ({#4+(6*((#2-#1)/(#3*60))},{1.2*#2});
% axes
\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- ({(6*(#2-#1)/(#3*60))+#4},0) node[right] {\huge time (\si{\hour})};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (0,{1.2*#2}) node[above] {\huge T (\si{\celsius})};
% xticks and yticks
  \foreach \x in {1,2,...,{(6*(#2-#1)/(#3*60))+#4)}}  \node at (\x, 0) [below] {\huge\x};
  \foreach \y in {100,200,...,#2}  \node at (0,\y) [left] {\huge\y};
% temperature
\begin{scope}[ultra thick, red]
\draw (0,#1) -- ({(#2-#1)/(#3*60)},#2);
\draw ({(#2-#1)/(#3*60)},#2) -- ({(#2-#1)/(#3*60)+#4},#2);
\draw[thin, dashed, blue] ({(#2-#1)/(#3*60)+#4},#2) -- ({(1.5*(#2-#1)/(#3*60))+#4},#1);
\draw ({(#2-#1)/(#3*60)+#4},#2) .. controls ({(2.0*(#2-#1)/(#3*60))+#4},{#1+0.2*(#2-#1)}) and ({(5.0*(#2-#1)/(#3*60))+#4},#1) .. ({(6*(#2-#1)/(#3*60))+#4},#1);
\end{scope}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} [x=2cm,y=0.01cm]
\ProgTemp{20}{500}{10}{3}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I suspect something related to the rounding of the value, which should be integer, but can't find my way around (!) this problem.
How can I transform `{(6*(#2-#1)/(#3*60))+#4)}` to an integer value ?

[image]

Comment: Your code is not compiling without errors. There is at least one typo, i.e. grey instead of gray in your color definition and missing numbers/units.

Comment: @JMP I know it is not compiling without error, but I get a graph with only the first two ticks on the x axis. My question is how to round the calculated value ans transform it to an integer which could be accepted.

Comment: I see... See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\pgfmathparse{floor(x)} \pgfmathresult`

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc}
\newcommand{\ProgTemp}[4]% #1=T_amb,#2=T_plateau, #3=rate, #4=t_plateau
{
    % grid
    \draw[style=help lines, ystep=100, xstep=1, ultra thin, color=gray] (0,0) grid ({#4+(6*((#2-#1)/(#3*60))},{1.2*#2});
    % axes
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- ({(6*(#2-#1)/(#3*60))+#4},0) node[right] {\huge time (\si{\hour})};
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (0,{1.2*#2}) node[above] {\huge T (\si{\celsius})};
    % xticks and yticks
    \pgfmathparse{floor(6*(#2-#1)/(#3*60))+#4)};
    \foreach \x in {1,2,...,\pgfmathresult}  \node at (\x, 0) [below] {\huge\x};
    \foreach \y in {100,200,...,#2}  \node at (0,\y) [left] {\huge\y};
    % temperature
    \begin{scope}[ultra thick, red]
        \draw (0,#1) -- ({(#2-#1)/(#3*60)},#2);
        \draw ({(#2-#1)/(#3*60)},#2) -- ({(#2-#1)/(#3*60)+#4},#2);
        \draw[thin, dashed, blue] ({(#2-#1)/(#3*60)+#4},#2) -- ({(1.5*(#2-#1)/(#3*60))+#4},#1);
        \draw ({(#2-#1)/(#3*60)+#4},#2) .. controls ({(2.0*(#2-#1)/(#3*60))+#4},{#1+0.2*(#2-#1)}) and ({(5.0*(#2-#1)/(#3*60))+#4},#1) .. ({(6*(#2-#1)/(#3*60))+#4},#1);
    \end{scope}
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} [x=2cm,y=0.01cm]
        \ProgTemp{20}{500}{10}{3}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly. Maybe I should change the title and add a `rounding` tag

Comment: Changing your title is probably a good idea, but since rounding is not existing as a tag yet, its probably not such a good idea to add it.

Comment: I tried and failed to add a tag (needs more reputation to create one). Anyway the title is more explicit and to the point.

Comment: I'm trying to combine it with `\pgfplotstablegetelem`, e.g. `\pgfmathparse{floor(\pgfplotsretval)}`, but I only get 0.0 for `pgfmathresult`. Any hint as to how to combine those?